# Copy folder and sub folders with files but skip files in root folder using windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd

How to skip files in the root folder but copy sub folders and their files.

Comment: Have you tried [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and its `/XD` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command line.  Change `f:\1`  Start it in your folder of choice.

`for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /ad') do @%windir%\System32\xcopy /is "%a" "f:\1\%a"`

batch.  Change `f:\1`  Start it in your folder of choice.

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do @%windir%\System32\xcopy /is "%%a" "f:\1\%%a"`

shortcut.  Change `f:\1`  Start it in your folder of choice.

`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /ad') do @%windir%\System32\xcopy /is "%a" "f:\1\%a"`

for `%a` in a directory list of directory names only (`dir /b /ad`) xcopy `%a` + sub-directories and xcopy w/o asking if `%a` is a file or a directory if xcopy more than one file (`xcopy /is "%a"`).  **You do not have to xcopy to a different drive (i.e. `xcopy /is "%a" "backup\%a"`) but it must be to directory that you are not trying to copy**.  Double quotes takes care of spaces in the path/filename.

for help:

`xcopy /?`

`dir /?`

`for /?`